# firebase credential missing in auth error catch

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Logging in with firebase auth, I would like to link accounts with the same email address. I mean that when you log in with a facebook account that has the email address foo@gmail.com, and this email is already registered with a google account in your app, then I would like to link those facebook & google accounts.

For this I'm basing myself on the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/link-accounts#handling_the_account-exists-with-different-credential_error

I'm using firebase v9 (beta), and don't get a credential property on my error.

```
        getRedirectResult(auth).then((userCredential: UserCredential | null) => {
        // do stuff
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.credential) //undefined
        })
```

The rest of the error object is filled in though (email, code, etc.)

Is this a breaking change with v9, or am I missing something?

EDIT,
this is what the error looks like

```
{
  "code": "auth/email-already-in-use",
  "customData": {
    "appName": "[DEFAULT]",
    "email": "hidden@gmail.com",
    "_tokenResponse": {
      "federatedId": "http://facebook.com/2105242186275845",
      "providerId": "facebook.com",
      "email": "hidden@gmail.com",
      "emailVerified": false,
      "firstName": "hidden",
      "fullName": "hidden",
      "lastName": "hidden",
      "photoUrl": "https://graph.facebook.com/hidden/picture",
      "displayName": "hidden",
      "context": "",
      "oauthAccessToken": "hidden",
      "oauthExpireIn": 5100325,
      "rawUserInfo": "{\"name\":\"hidden\",\"last_name\":\"hidden\",\"granted_scopes\":[\"email\",\"public_profile\"],\"id\":\"2105242186275845\",\"first_name\":\"hidden\",\"email\":\"hidden@gmail.com\",\"picture\":{\"data\":{\"is_silhouette\":false,\"width\":100,\"url\":\"https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid\\hidden\\u0026height\\u003d100\\u0026width\\u003d100\\u0026ext\\u003d1629017191\\u0026hash\\u003dAeTs_VEMazok9d75eG4\",\"height\":100}}}",
      "errorMessage": "EMAIL_EXISTS",
      "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyAssertionResponse"
    }
  },
  "name": "FirebaseError"
}
```

Comment: Can you please share what the error looks like? Is it account exists error or something else?

Comment: @Dharmaraj, I've edited my question with the error object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly identified that this will be a breaking change in v9.

In v9, the [`AuthError` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v9/auth.autherror.md#autherror_interface) will look like:

| Property | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `appName` | `string` | The name of the Firebase App which triggered this error. |
| `email` | `string | undefined` | The email of the user's account, used for sign-in/linking |
| `phoneNumber` | `string | undefined` | The phone number of the user's account, used for sign-in/linking |
| `tenantId` | `string | undefined` | The tenant ID being used for sign-in/linking |
| `code` | `string` | The Firebase error code identifying this error |
| `message` | `string` | An accessor for the friendly error message for this error code from [`prodErrorMap`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v9/auth.md#proderrormap) (simple messages) or [`debugErrorMap`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v9/auth.md#debugerrormap) (verbose messages) as appropriate |

**Note:** It's important to note that properties like `email` and `phoneNumber` are currently nested under the `customData` property, it is yet to be decided if accessors will be available to hoist them up to the top level or if you'll need to use `error.customData.email` and so on.

Importantly, you can see that [v8's `credential` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.AuthError#optional-credential) is omitted. In v9, this property isn't parsed automatically and you are expected to handball it to [`OAuthProvider.credentialFromError()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v9/auth.oauthprovider.md#oauthprovidercredentialfromerror) like so:

```
getRedirectResult(auth)
  .then((userCredential: UserCredential | null) => {
    // do stuff
  })
  .catch(error => {
    const credential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
    console.error("Auth failed with error: ", {
      code: error.code,
      email: error.email,
      credential
    });
  })
```

The documentation for this is yet to be updated and is being tracked as [`firebase-js-sdk` Issue 5057](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5057).

**Note:** A Facebook user doesn't have to share their email with you, so expect it to be sometimes unavailable.